# MongoDB find by ObjectId not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```js
> db.findOne()
> {
  _id: 609d1c45d6e9b228e0c65cad,
  state: 'in',
  employee_id: '606cef9a28702415c0682c52',
  checkin_at: 1620909125476,
  location: {},
  checkout_at: null
}
```

```js
> let ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId
> db.findOne({ _id: ObjectId('609d1c45d6e9b228e0c65cad') })
> null
```

Please, I have tried all the suggested answers yet it always return null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The ObjectId casting syntax is fine, i'm wondering what's `db` in your code? can you show what type it is?

Comment: It's actually funny how a comment solved my problem. The problem was that I was using `require('mongodb').MongoClient` instead of `require('mongodb').ObjectId`